# Is it possible to have hard real-time with lexical scope?

Tags: embedded, lisp, scope, real-time, lexical

I was reading [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDIQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fportal.acm.org%2Fcitation.cfm%3Fid%3D1093422&rct=j&q=the%20funarg%20problem&ei=NQC8TfrODIHZgAfo_Zm9BQ&usg=AFQjCNGb3R0XNMTJyY0iqR8XtTsA9yN4Mw&cad=rja) about the funarg problem, which is really the problem of maintaining the environments of lexical closures. It's an old paper and I'm not sure if the author's conclusions still hold, but he strongly implies that, in order to have lexical rather than dynamic scope, you have to abandon the traditional C-style stack, and instead have a tree structure of environments, allocated from the heap.

Does this make it impossible to have lexically scoped closures in any hard-real-time system? in real-time embedded systems, where latencies are measured in microseconds, heap allocation is typically forbidden because of the non-deterministic latency it introduces.

This has been an idle curiosity of mine, because I make my bread mostly as a firmware developer where C is the de facto language, and for a while now it seems I've been using my brain power to figure out how to force C to let me do things that come for free in more sophisticated languages. Consequently, I've begun to wonder whether you could implement a micro-lisp compiler specifically for hard-real-time embedded microcontroller-based systems.

As a side note: I've lately gained great insights into deep topics like how closures and objects are equivalent and so forth, and it gives me greater awe of guys like Stallman and Rich Hickey, and Paul Graham. Implementing Lisp from the ground up seems like a daunting task to me. It's hard to know where to start. (Maybe with PG's implementation of McCarthy's original eval function, IDK). Anyway, I digress.

Comment: You may want to look at Lua's implementation of closures, as described in http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf (page 8+, but the rest may be interesting as well). It's relatively sophisticated and has much lower overhead than straightforward implementations.

Comment: This is cool, and, as you say, sophisticated.

Comment: Here's a paper on embedded Scheme: "BIT: A very compact Scheme system for embedded applications" (http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~dube/)

Answer (score 3):

Lexical scope is obviously possible with "hard real-time" -- after all, you say that you're using C for real-time applications, and C *is* a lexically scoped language.  My guess is that you're actually concerned about first-class functions, not lexical scope.  Assuming that, there's a whole bunch of known compilation techniques for dealing with first-class functions efficiently.

First of all, what you'll see in textbooks etc is almost always doing the usual tree-shaped environment, but in practice that's not needed at all if functions are not used as values.  Practically every decent functional language compiler will identify such code and will use the stack instead, so there's zero overhead for allocation.  (Note that at this point this means that if you limit yourself to the kind of things that you write in C then no allocation is needed.)  Then, there's a bunch of additional ways to reduce allocations -- for example, consider something like `(lambda (x) (* x 9))` -- this function doesn't really *close* over any free identifiers, and therefore compilers will [lift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_lifting) it to the top so there's a single copy of the function and, again, no allocation.  (Related note: with this optimization you already get more than what C gives you and still no allocation.)

There's a whole bunch of [additional optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aImplementation_of_functional_programming_languages) that avoid allocation, but of course there *are* cases where you really need to allocate a new closure.  But these places are statically identifiable, and if you really care about such allocations then it shouldn't be difficult to hack up a compiler that warns you about such allocations.  There have been a number of such languages, see for example [GOAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Oriented_Assembly_Lisp), the very low level [prescheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PreScheme).  But IME most people quickly get the hang of things and it's getting obvious where allocations happen -- so you get the benefit of a high level language, and when it gets to some code that you want to optimize, it's easy to see where allocation happens, and it's easy to avoid it in the usual ways.  (And of course, all of this is unrelated to optimizing allocations.)

Answer (score 1):

I found some real-time allocators so I'd say. lexical scope in real-time is possible:

http://rtportal.upv.es/rtmalloc/

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.441&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Adding to your digession, before writing my own micro-lisp, I would try to find or port [lua](http://www.lua.org) for the embedded system in question. It is very small and offers much of LISP: first-class functions, closures, no continuations but co-routines.

> Lua is small
>
> Adding Lua to an application does not
>   bloat it. The tarball for Lua 5.1.4,
>   which contains source code,
>   documentation, and examples, takes
>   212K compressed and 860K uncompressed.
>   The source contains around 17000 lines
>   of C. Under Linux, the Lua interpreter
>   built with all standard Lua libraries
>   takes 153K and the Lua library takes
>   203K.
>
> Lua is free
>
> Lua is free open-source software,
>   distributed under a very liberal
>   license (the well-known MIT license).
>   It may be used for any purpose,
>   including commercial purposes, at
>   absolutely no cost. Just download it
>   and use it.

Comment: Ah, this is a *very* interesting paper! Embedded developers typically circumvent the lack of heap using fixed-size pools, which is a pain. Having a real heap with bounded time for malloc() would be a blessing indeed.

Comment: Should be first *class* functions -- first order is roughly the opposite of that.  Also, that's really saying the same as "closures" (closures are the common implementation technique for first-class functions).

Comment: @Eli Thanks, what I meant to write was higher order functions. Corrected.

Comment: Well, higher order functions is nothing special -- and in fact C has them.  It's first class functions that bring in closure allocation issues.

Comment: @Johnny - Even with a bounded time allocator, firmware developers are still likely to be wary of using a general-purpose dynamic memory because it's difficult (or impossible) to deterministically prove that allocations will succeed (especially due to fragmentation).

Comment: @Eli I slept over it, memories came back and you are right here.